# Simple watir webdriver script failing in jenkins

Tags: ruby, selenium, jenkins, watir-webdriver

I newly installed jenkins in my local and I need to run a watir webdriver script in jenkins which is running successfully in command prompt. Below is the simple watir script.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b=Watir::Browser.new
b.goto "http://www.google.com"
b.text_field(:class => "gsfi").set "Avinash"
b.close
```

I saved the above piece of code into a file called test.rb and it is running fine while I am executing the same on a command prompt. But, I just installed Jenkins and created a Freestyle project. I placed this test.rb file in the jenkins project workspace location, and in the configure section of this newly created project, under build section I added "Execute Windows Batch Command" and I just gave `ruby test.rb`. Now I clicked on Build Now of my project and I expected to get a browser getting triggered and execute my Watir script. But, I did not see any browser getting triggered and the job failed. Below is the error that I am facing

```
C:\Users\sony\.jenkins\jobs\test\workspace>ruby test.rb 
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:152:in `rbuf_fill'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in `read_new'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1414:in `block in transport_request'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `catch'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `transport_request'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1384:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1377:in `block in request'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:107:in `response_for'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:58:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:664:in `raw_execute'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:642:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:133:in `get'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:33:in `to'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:77:in `goto'
    from test.rb:5:in `<main>'

C:\Users\sony\.jenkins\jobs\test\workspace>exit 1 
Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please let me know what I missed here so that I can see browser getting triggered immediately after I hit on build now in my jenkins an execute my watir script.

Comment: Can you reach www.google.com from the Jenkings server? (Assuming it is not running locally?)

Comment: @Matheus208 I hope I am able to. May I know how can I confirm you practically from jenkins server whether I am able reach google or not ?

Comment: run `$ whoami` command under `build` -> `Shell Script` section of your job's section. now, switch to that user from your command prompt `sudo su <username>` and run `ruby.rb`. If not runs then give the file permission to that user.

Comment: What browsers do you have installed on the jenkins box? This message is timing out talking to the browser.

Comment: @DavidAmbler It has both firefox and chrome installed. Basically it is not a separate box . It is installed in the same box where I am running my test.rb where it is working perfectly alright.  I am really looking for the browser to popup and run my watir script the moment I click on build now of my jenkins job.

Answer (score 0):

99% of the time this is due to a browser and driver mismatch. It could be that it's not finding the right driver on your Path, or that the browser it's loading is a different version than otherwise.